# Is there any way to return all objects defined in a function in R?

Tags: r

Is there any way to return all objects defined in a function in R?

Here's a little example of what I'm trying to do. I want to return everything I've assigned a value to inside this function (`dave`, `mark`, `xx`, `z` (if exists)). The print statement is superfluous.

I normally wouldn't even try to do this, it's just I'm converting a `source`d file into a function, and previously all objects were sourced into the global environment, which is what I still need, and I'd rather not create an enormous list of all the objects at the end of the function. 
Ideally, after running the function, all the objects are in the global environment and can be accessed from the list. (Automatically delisting and leaving them as standalone objects would be great.) Perhaps this should be a class?

It errors out if any of these are `NULL`, if for example, `y` is supplied as `NULL` in the function definition arguments (i.e. `test_func <- function(x = c(1, 2), y = NULL) ...`).

```r
test_func <- function(x = c(1, 2), y = 3) {
  xx <- x * x
  if(!is.null(y)) z <- x * y
  mark <- "hello"
  dave <- data.frame(x = x, xx = xx)
  whatshere <- ls()
  print(whatshere)
  whatsout <- list()
  for (i in 1:length(whatshere)) {
    whatsout[[i]] <- get(whatshere[[i]])
  }
  names(whatsout) <- whatshere
  return(whatsout)
}
test_func()
#> [1] "dave" "mark" "x"    "xx"   "y"    "z"
#> $dave
#>   x xx
#> 1 1  1
#> 2 2  4
#> 
#> $mark
#> [1] "hello"
#> 
#> $x
#> [1] 1 2
#> 
#> $xx
#> [1] 1 4
#> 
#> $y
#> [1] 3
#> 
#> $z
#> [1] 3 6
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: For anyone coming to this question, Konrad's answer works perfectly, and I'm using this to unlist everything into the global environment:

`x <- test_func();`
`for (i in 1:length(x)) {
  assign(names(x[i]), x[[i]])
};`
`rm(x)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any way to return all objects defined in a function in R?

Literally, there is<sup>1</sup>:

```
as.list(environment())
```

However, I’d generally recommend *against* this: **be explicit**, name all objects that you want to return individually:

```
list(
    foo = foo,
    bar = bar,
    …
)
```

---

<sup>1</sup> This will include arguments, since these are just locally defined values. To exclude formal arguments, do this:

```
values = as.list(environment())
values[setdiff(names(values), names(formals()))]
```

Comment: Ooh, brilliant, thank you. Yes, I totally agree, I wouldn't have even dreamt this up except for I found myself in the situation, and my return list would be enormous. Thank you!

Comment: @RobertMyles See update, I forgot handling the arguments. Doing so makes it messier.

Comment: ...but much better :-) . This is great, Konrad, really appreciate it.